# filter in ascending order in Python/django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a filter in **Python/django**. All the data is coming from DB. This query currently works but **I want to able show it in ascending order of Name first and Description after**. Any assistance would be helpful.

```
query = request.GET.get('q')
   if query:
       data = Data.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description_icontains=query)).distinct()
```

Comment: use [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)?

Comment: I am trying like this but doesn't work..
data = Data.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(sub_name__icontains=query) |
                                   Q(description__icontains=query)).order_by('name').distinct()

Comment: Try `data = Data.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(sub_name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)).order_by('name', 'description').distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
data = Data.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query | Q(description__icontains=query)).order_by("name", "description").distinct()
```

or

```py
data = Data.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains="query") | Q(description__icontains="query")).order_by("name", "description").distinct()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! If you can add a link to the documentation for this, or explain a little about why it works, then your answer may be more useful to others in the future! :)